# using a blob with open layer. error : "Invalid byte order value"

Tags: openlayers

my use of openlayer is on an image and not on the world map.
with open layer version 9, I need to upload images (upload file) and include it in open layer.

for this, I convert the file into Blob format because open layer requires it (I can't find any other techniques).

the problem is that I still get an error message  "Invalid byte order value"

I attached the stackblitz with the error

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9xasby?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Findex.html,src%2Fmain.ts,src%2Ffeatures%2Fopen-layer%2Fopen-layer-main%2Fopen-layer-main.component.ts&template=node&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: Your stackblitz works perfectly for me with a valid geotiff (e.g. download https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/data/example.tif and choose it from your downloads folder) so I presume the file you are using is not a valid geotiff).

Comment: Indeed, I was using JPGs. I didn't know the TIFF format. Thank you for your analysis